# Target machine refusing connection with client [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, python-multithreading

When i run my code on my own machine the client and server connect smoothly but when attempting connection to another machine (server hosted on my computer and another computer trying to connect) i get this error: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

**My code:**

**server.py**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((SERVER, PORT))

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message, sender):
    for client in clients:
        if client != sender:
            client.send(message)

def handle_client(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(HEADER).decode('utf-8')
            if message:
                if message == "!DISCONNECT":
                    index = clients.index(client)
                    clients.remove(client)
                    client.close()
                    nickname = nicknames[index]
                    nicknames.remove(nickname)
                    broadcast(f"[{nickname}] has left the chat.".encode('utf-8'), client)
                    break
                else:
                    nickname = nicknames[clients.index(client)]
                    broadcast(f"[{nickname}] {message}".encode('utf-8'), client)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            broadcast(f"[{nickname}] has left the chat.".encode('utf-8'), client)
            break

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {address} connected.")
        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(HEADER).decode('utf-8')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {len(clients)}")
        broadcast(f"[CONNECTION] {nickname} has joined the chat.".encode('utf-8'), client)
        client.send("Connected to the server!".encode('utf-8'))
        client.send("You can start chatting.".encode('utf-8'))
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        client_thread.start()

print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((SERVER, PORT))

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
            if message != DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("[ERROR] Connection closed.")
            client.close()
            break

def send():
    while True:
        message = input()
        client.send(message.encode(FORMAT))
        if message == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            client.close()
            break

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send)
send_thread.start()
```

I've tried changing the port, IP and my firewall settings (randomly tbf) but still no luck. Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: Did you try to telnet into the server/port from the remote client ?

Comment: Don't bind server sockets to specific IP addresses whatever their source. Bind them to `0.0.0.0`. Otherwise you are ruling out clients on all other subnets willy-nilly.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the server to the ip address returned by this:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

At least "on my computer" this will return ip address of a localhost, aka, 127.0.0.1.

This is the IP address also in the the remote machine so your remote client is trying to connect to itself and since the server isn't running on the remote, it will fail and  you get the error you get ...

Either you need to find what is the default outgoing network device - that can receive the traffic from remote ip addresses or just us "0.0.0.0" as value for `SERVER` variable. Using 0.0.0.0 will "bind" the server to all available ip addresses of the machine.